# My wired connection says it's connected, but nothing works. (12.04)

Tags: networking

After spending hours trying to get my wired Comcast Internet to work on Ubuntu, I thought I had finally got it to work when I discovered that I needed to set it as a static IP by setting the Ipv4 as manual and filling in the required information (I was able to see the up and down arrows afterwards). It only took a few minutes to realize I still had more work to do. Firefox pages load indefinitely and downloads from the software center stay in waiting mode. My question is, what did I do wrong?

My stats and such:

```
Mac is BC:AE:C5:99:FD:14
```

(For cloned I just put the same). 
I don't think there is any 802.1x security so I left it unchecked. 
`IP is 24.23.188.52`.
`Subnet mask is 255.255.255.0`.
`Gateway is 192.168.1.1`.
`Dns servers are 75.75.75.75, 75.75.76.76, 192.168.1.1, 208.67.222.222`.
Search domains I didn't know any so I put google.com (that's probably the issue but I don't know).
Also Ipv6 I left as Automatic.
My pc is dual booted with Windows 7 64bit and Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

EDIT: Ok, I tried NlightNfotis's directions, here is what happened:

Pinging www.askubuntu.com returned `tradping: unknown host www.askubuntu.com`  Doing traceroute returned `the program 'traceroute' can be installed in the following packages:  inetutils-traceroute 
 traceroute`
It then told me I could install it with sudo apt-get, and I tried that but it "could not find the package"

Adding 8.8.8.8 to DNS did nothing, unfortunately.
 8.8.4.4 does nothing also.

I am very new to Linux and Ubuntu, by the way.

Setting the connection to DHCP doesn't disconnect it, but the internet still refuses to load anything.

Still have nothing, netstat -nr doesnt show any items under any category.

Here is a random pic with data, maybe it'll help.
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?zk2yjn7khfocf94# (IPv4 from when its on manual)

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Now that you have set the DHCP settings to automatic, let's try to restart the network to have the DHCP server assign it an IP address. Try this: sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

Comment: Ok. Btw I tried to post pics but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: Hmm. It said something, but it made not very much sense. Pic: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?yho3660f5q6mcrc#              also maybe this will help? http://www.mediafire.com/view/?gv0dbnbgo4vlgrs# its from when I entered ifconfig into Terminal.

Comment: Great! Check to see now if you have network connectivity.

Comment: I wonder why it gives you this ip: 24.23.188.52 if the gateway is at 192.168.1.1. It doesn't make any sense. Normally the DHCP server should assign something like 192.168.1.3.

Comment: This doesn't seem normal. I would like to see if the gateway is indeed at 192.168.1.1 and it's not something like 24.23.188.1. Can you try running this: sudo netstat -nr

Comment: This is weird. I had connectivity(not internet) when i logged out of Ubuntu, but logging back in it refused to connect with DHCP. Pic: http://www.mediafire.com/view/?s8ku3y1izayzk0v#              I'll run that command now

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your DNS server to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (Google's public dns servers) and see if this shows any changes.

Also try to change the network settings from **manual mode** to **Automatic (DHCP)**. I suggest doing so if your network router supports a DHCP server, which automatically assigns IP addresses to hosts on the same network:
[image]

Comment: OK I'll try that, will post results in a few minutes.

Comment: I had it on DHCP before, it never worked for me. Isn't that for a dynamic Ip? I'm pretty sure mine is static.

Comment: There is a difference between Public network and internal network IPs. You may have a static public network IP, and still have dynamic internal IPs.

Comment: Oh. I'll try that then.

Answer (score 0):

In Edit Connections make sure the Connection Name is Auto(eth0) ie ethzero-MTU is set to automatic-IP v 4 settings are Method: Automatic(DHCP), both boxes are ticked for 1. Require IP4 addressingfor this connection to complete, and
2. Available to all users, In IP v 6 settings, make sure Method: is set to Ignore, and tick the box for Available to all users